# List files sorted by the number of lines they contain

Tags: bash, shell, files, wc

How can I list the number of lines in the files in `/group/book/four/word`, sorted by the number of lines they contain?

The `ls -l` command lists the files but does not sort them.

Comment: Do you want the files listed by number of lines, or list the number of lines in the files or both? `ls -l` doesn't give the number of lines. `ls -lS` sorts file by size with some `ls` implementations (_size_ being number of bytes in the content).

Answer (score 54):

You should use a command like this:

```
find /group/book/four/word/ -type f -exec wc -l {} + | sort -rn
```

- `find` : search for files on the path you want. If you don't want it recursive, and your `find` implementation supports it, you should add `-maxdepth 1` just before the `-exec` option.
- `exec` : tells the command to execute `wc -l` on every file.
- `sort -rn` : sort the results numerically in reverse order. From greater to lower.

(that assumes file names don't contain newline characters).

Comment: Note that when passed more than one file (or with some implementations, more than one file that it can read), `wc` will also print a `total` line, so here you'll also get one or more "total" lines unless there is only one file. You can pipe to `grep /` to remove them.

Comment: how can I filter to show only file with X lines minimum (exclude X = 0 line for exemple) ?

Comment: What's the meaning of "+" plus symbol?

Comment: @廖茂生: See [these answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195939/what-is-meaning-of-in-finds-exec-command) for the meaning of the plus sign in `-exec`.

Answer (score 15):

### Non-recursive

Probably the simplest version if you don't need recursivity :

```
wc -l /group/book/four/word/*|sort -n
```

`wc` counts lines (option `-l`) in every (but hidden) (`*`) files under `/group/book/four/word/`, and `sort` sorts the result (through the pipe `|`) numerically (option `-n`).

### Recursive

Someone made a comment to this answer mentioning `grep -rlc`, before to suppress it.  Indeed `grep` is a great alternative, especially if you need recursivity :

```
grep -rc '^' /group/book/four/word/|tr ':' ' '|sort -n -k2
```

will count (option `-c`) recursively (option `-r`) lines matching (`grep`) `'^'` (that is, beginning of lines) in the directory `/group/book/four/word/`.  Then you have to replace the colon by a space, e.g. using `tr`, to help `sort`, which you want to sort numerically (option `-n`) on the second column (option `-k2`).

**Update :** See Stephane's comment about possible limitations and how you can actually get rid of `tr`.

Comment: `grep -c .` counts the lines that contain at least one valid character. Use `grep -c '^'` to count all the lines (will also count trailing characters after the last newline with some `grep` implementations). Note that not all `grep` implementations support a `-r` and behaviour varies among those that do. You don't need to translate `:`s (colon, not semicolon) to spaces for `sort`. Just use `-t:`. Note that that assumes file names don't contain `:` or blank or newline characters.

Comment: Thanks for posting your non-recursive solution; I didn't know `wc` gave such a handy total all if you pass multiple paths. Coupling that functionality with the wild card and the pipe to `sort` is really clean.

Answer (score 8):

With `zsh`:

```
lines() REPLY=$(wc -l < $REPLY)
print -rC1 /group/book/four/word/*(.no+lines)
```

We define a new *sorting* function `lines` that replies with the number of lines in the file. And we use the `o+lines` glob qualifier which together with `n` (for numeric sort), defines how the results of the glob are ordered. (`.` also added to only check regular files).

That makes no assumption on what character the file names may contain other than hidden files (those starting with `.`) are omitted. Add the `D` glob qualifier if you want them as well.

Defining a `lines` function is useful when you often do something like that, but for a one-off, you could also do it in one go with:

```
print -rC1 /group/book/four/word/*(.noe['REPLY=$(wc -l < $REPLY)'])
```

From another shell, simply run:

```
zsh -c '
  print -rC1 /group/book/four/word/*(.noe['\''REPLY=$(wc -l < $REPLY)'\''])'
```

Or to store it in a `ksh93`/`bash` array if you really had to use those shells:

```
typeset -a array
eval "
  array=(
    $(
      zsh -c '
        () {
          print -r -- "${(qq)@}"
        } /group/book/four/word/*(N.noe['\''REPLY=$(wc -l < $REPLY)'\''])'
    )
  )
"
```

(here using proper single-quote quoting (with the `qq` parameter expansion flag) for the `eval`uation to be safe).

Comment: OP is tagged with `bash` only...

Comment: @l0b0 that doesn't mean that the next person who needs this will also be running bash.

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify whether you also want the files in any subdirectories of `/group/book/four/word`. The `find` solution in jherran's answer will descend into subdirectories. If that is not wanted, use the shell instead:

```
for file in ./*; do [ -f "$file" ] && wc -l "$file"; done | sort -n
```

If your file names can contain newlines, you can use something like:

```
for file in ./*; do 
    [ -f "$file" ] && 
        printf "%lu %s\0" "$(wc -l < "$file")" "$file"
done | sort -zn | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Finally, if you *do* want to descend into subdirectories, you can use this in `bash` 4 or above:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in ./**/*; do [ -f "$file" ] && wc -l "$file"; done | sort -n
```

Note that versions of `bash` prior to 4.3 were following symlinks when recursively descending the directory tree (like `zsh`'s or `tcsh`'s `***/*`).

Also, all solutions above will ignore hidden files (those whose name starts with a `.`, use `shopt -s dotglob` to include them) and will also include the line count of symbolic links (which the `find` approach will not).

Comment: Note that other differences from jherran's solution is that yours will also consider symlink to regular files (`-xtype f` in GNU find or `*(-.)` in zsh) and will omit hidden files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, clarified. Why the `%lu` in `printf`? As I recall, that means long unsigned decimal, is it really necessary? Why not treat the number as a string? Does it make a difference?

Comment: If the wc output is empty (for instance because the file is not readable), then that will expand to `0` instead of the empty string, which is slightly better. Some sort implementations work with unsigned integers some with signed. `%lu` sounds like the safest bet, but it doesn't probably matter as if you have `2^31` lines, that will take ages anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to install [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) a really fast file finder written in Rust (you should install it, it's great to have anyway)

```
fd --type=file . | xargs wc -l | sort -n
```

Basically `fd` lists the files, xargs will pass the list of files to `wc` (stands for word count but passing -l will make it count lines) then finally it's sorted from least number of lines to greatest using `sort -n`.

Comment: this seems like the most intuitive, unixy way to do it.

Comment: Add `--total=never` to wc if you want to process its output, otherwise it will add a line with the total number of lines which might break things

Answer (score 0):

Since the solution provided by @SkippyleGrandGourou didn't work for me, here is my recursive solution using `find`:

```
find <folder> -name "<filter>" -exec wc {} \; | sort
```

Example:

```
find . -name "*.jsp" -exec wc {} \; | sort
```