# Find files containing keyword and show only the file path and the line number

Tags: text-processing, files, find

I'd like to find all the Java files containing keyword `File.createTempFile` with the line number. Here's what I did:

```
$ find . -name "*.java" | xargs grep -n "File.createTempFile"
./nuxeo-studio-test/src/test/java/com/nuxeo/studio/web/StudioServletTest.java:162:            File tmpFile = File.createTempFile(jarEntryName, null, Environment.getDefault().getTemp());
./nuxeo-studio-ui/src/main/java/com/nuxeo/studio/core/builders/WorkflowFeatureBuilder.java:421:            tmp = File.createTempFile(".workflow-to-zip", ".tmp", workspace.getRoot());
./nuxeo-studio-ui/src/test/java/com/nuxeo/studio/core/backup/TestS3Backup.java:101:        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5), ".tmp");
./nuxeo-studio-ui/target/classes/com/nuxeo/studio/core/builders/WorkflowFeatureBuilder.java:421:            tmp = File.createTempFile(".workflow-to-zip", ".tmp", workspace.getRoot());
./nuxeo-studio-web/src/main/java/com/nuxeo/studio/web/v1/ProjectResource.java:191:            File zip = File.createTempFile(filename + "-", ".zip", tempRepo);
```

However, I found this result too long to read. I'd like to keep only the file path and the line number. Here's expected result:

```
./nuxeo-studio-test/src/test/java/com/nuxeo/studio/web/StudioServletTest.java:162
./nuxeo-studio-ui/src/main/java/com/nuxeo/studio/core/builders/WorkflowFeatureBuilder.java:421
./nuxeo-studio-ui/src/test/java/com/nuxeo/studio/core/backup/TestS3Backup.java:101
./nuxeo-studio-ui/target/classes/com/nuxeo/studio/core/builders/WorkflowFeatureBuilder.java:421
./nuxeo-studio-web/src/main/java/com/nuxeo/studio/web/v1/ProjectResource.java:191
```

Could somebody teach me how to do so?

Comment: Use `grep -L` or pipe your output to `awk '{ print $1 }'`. The later won't work with file paths that contain spaces.

Comment: @jordanm, the 2nd solution works fine: it contains additional `:`, but it's good enough. I cannot use the first one successfully, could you give the full command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way with `awk`:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec awk '/PATTERN/{print FILENAME,FNR}' {} +
```

or, if you wanted to emulate `grep`'s output:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec awk '/PATTERN/{printf("%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR)}' {} +
```

Comment: It works fine. Could you explain what does `{} +`, please?

Comment: @MincongHuang - [see the answers here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/195939)

Answer (score 3):

With `pcregrep`, you could do:

```
pcregrep --include='\.java$' -rHno1 '()File\.createTempFile' .
```

The output will be looking like:

```
./path/to/file.java:12:
```

If the pattern appears more than once on a line, there will be as many lines output. If you don't want that, you could change it to:

```
pcregrep --include='\.java$' -rHno1 '^().*?File\.createTempFile' .
```

Answer (score 2):

```
keyW='File.createTempFile'
find . -type f -name '*.java' -exec perl -slne '
  print "$ARGV:$." if /\Q$k\E/; $. = 0 if eof;
' -- -k="$keyW" -- {} +
```

Comment: The results found are correct, but their line numbers are wrong: the number shown refers to the file index in the result.

Comment: You'll need to *not* use `{} +` to avoid the `xargs` grouping, or tell `perl` to  reset the line number between files, see `perldoc -f eof` for details.

Comment: @Thrig+Mincong: Thanks for spotting the error. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
esport keyW='File.createTempFile'
find . -name '*.java' -type f -exec sh -c '
   grep -hn "$keyW" "$1" | cut -d":" -f1 |
   while IFS=: read -r n x; do
      printf "%s:%s\n" "$1" "$n"
   done
' {} {} \;
```

## Notes:

`grep` has to be run 1/per file is the limiation for this method.

Comment: Not sure why, but the `print '%s:%s\n' "$1" "$n"` does not add linefeed `\n` correctly, even if I change it to `\\n`. So all the results are correct, but displayed in a single line.

Comment: Make them to be double quotes: like printf "%s:%s\n" "$1" "$n"

Comment: Yes, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter out the part you don't want:

```
grep -n … | cut -d : -f 1,2
```

(This assumes that your file names don't contain colons or newlines.)

Comment: Elegant solution!