# chmod all files in a directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

How do I change all files (different types including .sh, .py, and other executable files) in a known directory to permission 775 without listing all of the file names?

I mean "all" of them in that directory, no exception.

**UPDATED**: The command below actually solved the problem for me. Any explanations why "+" instead of a "\"?

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" -exec chmod 775 {} +
```

Comment: For the difference between "+" and "\", see [What is meaning of {} + in find's -exec command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195939/what-is-meaning-of-in-finds-exec-command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find and chmod

```
find path_to_dir -type f -name "*.*" -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

change `*.*` to the type of files you would like to change its permissions. `*.*` will apply the changes to all files in the directory.

Comment: As he just wants to change the permissions of the files no matter the type, he can omit `-name "*.*"`

Comment: I got this error: "find: missing argument to `-exec'" when I run this command in the terminal under my target directory. I'm using a . for the path_to_dir part of your answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, it actually worked. I left out the semicolon during my first try.